# Use clang-tidy to output issues with formatting

Tags: clang-format, clang-tidy

Is it possible to set up clang-tidy to output issues it has found with the formatting of the source code as defined by the `.clang-format` file. Basically, telling you what kind of changes clang-format would do if it ran on the file. Something along the lines of:

`Line 23: improper indentation, 4 spaces should be used`

`Line 47: opening brace for loops should be on the same line`

If not, would it be possible to write a custom check, which could do that for me?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can do this with clang-tidy since it parses the code to AST and doesn't care about formatting.

You can use `clang-format` with the `-output-replacements-xml` option.

The xml output will tell you what you want (what changes and where) but don't expect a nice output for human readers.

Sample:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<replacements xml:space='preserve' incomplete_format='false'>
<replacement offset='337' length='8'>&#13;&#10;&#13;&#10;  </replacement>
</replacements>
```